# MaterializeCSS Icon do not work on navbar in Angular 7

Tags: javascript, html, css, materialize, angular7

I am trying to use MaterializeCSS Icon to work on the navbar. In the code posted, arrow-drop_down doesn't seem to work. Instead, it shows just a text. Icons render on other pages except in the app.component.html file.

I tried to import the below code directly in the index.html file. Still the same result. Am I missing something here? Also, I cannot figure out a reason why Icons display in any other component apart from app.component.html

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you. Let me know if more details are required.

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```

index.html

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>UiCommunity</title>
  <base href="/">
  
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

app.component.html

```html
<!--The content below is only a placeholder and can be replaced.-->
<header>
  <nav class="white">
    <div class="container nav-wrapper">
      <a href="/" class="brand-logo">Community</a>
      <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
        <li>
          <a routerLink="/" routerLinkActive="active">HOME</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a routerLink="/event" routerLinkActive="active">EVENTS</a>
        </li>
        <li *ngIf="!authenticated()">
          <a routerLink="/login" routerLinkActive="active">LOGIN</a>
        </li>
        <li *ngIf=!authenticated()>
          <a routerLink="/register" routerLinkActive="active">SIGNUP</a>
        </li>
        <li *ngIf=authenticated()>
          <a routerLink="/logout" class="black-text">LOGOUT</a>
        </li>
        <li *ngIf=authenticated()>
          <a routerLink="/profile" class="dropdown-trigger black-text" data-target="dropdown1">PROFILE<i class="material-icons right">arrow_drop_down</i></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="btn waves-effect waves-lime lime darken-4 white-text">Donate</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <ul id='dropdown1' class='dropdown-content'>
    <li><a href="#!">one</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!">two</a></li>
    <li class="divider" tabindex="-1"></li>
    <li><a href="#!">three</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!"><i class="material-icons">view_module</i>four</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!"><i class="material-icons">cloud</i>five</a></li>
  </ul>
</header>
<main>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</main>
<footer></footer>
```

This is my style.css

```css
/* You can add global styles to this file, and also import other style files */
@import "../node_modules/materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.css";
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Philosopher');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons');
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to import your styles file directly on your app component ts/js file? If you got all the dependencies installed and it works on other pages, it is probably an importing or wrong path issue.

Comment: Keeping your answer as a reference, I was looking at why Materialize Icon did not work on the navbar. It seems like the font-family was overwritten and hence this issue. I had to override the font-family that Materialize Icon uses and it worked fine. Thanks for leading me.